# Filtering child collections using lodash javascript

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a service which return following JSON

```
  'data':     [{
    'category': {

        'Questions': [{
            aswers: [{
                Text: 'Text1'
            }],
            Data: 'TT'
        }],
        name: 'name1'
    }

}, {
    'category': {

        'Questions': [{
            aswers: [{
                Text: 'Text1'
            }],
            Data: 'TT'
        }],
        name: 'name1'
    }

}, {
    'category': {

        'Questions': [{
            aswers: [{
                Text: 'Text1'
            }],
            Data: 'TT'
        }],
        name: 'name1'
    }

}]
```

I want to write a filter query using lodash based on parent collection and child collections.

> where  category.Questions.data=='xxx' and category.Questions.aswers.Text='ddd'

i tried below query

```
var x=  _.filter(data.category, {Questions: [{Data: 'xxx', 'Questions.aswers.Text':'ddd'}] });
```

after that i want to update the value of the answer.Text selected objects.

relations ship is 
    data has collections of category objects
    category object have collection of answers objects
    answers object have collection of text objects

How can i achieve this?

Comment: you posted invalid json

Comment: sorry. the data structure is ,  data has collections of categories  , category has collection of answers ,  answer object have collection of text objects what i want to achieve is  where category.Questions.data=='xxx' and category.Questions.aswers.Text='ddd'

Comment: Copy of his valid json here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15670261/

Comment: Also... `answers` is spelled incorrectly as `aswers` :(

Comment: it was a spelling mistake still not getting valid answer.

Answer (score 1):

this is a bit tricky but here's how you can do it.

```
let matchingQuestions = _.chain(jsonData.data)
   .map(d => d.category.Questions) //So we have array of Questions arrays
   .flatten() //Now we have a single array with all Questions
   .filter({Data: 'xxx'}) //Filtering by Data
   .map('aswers') //After this we will have an array of answers arrays
                  //(only answers with matching Data definitely)
   .flatten() //A single array with all answers
   .filter({Text: 'ddd'}) //Now filtering by Text
   .value(); //Unwrapping lodash chain to get the result

   //Now you can update them however you want
   _.each(matchingQuestions, q => q.Text = 'Updated Text');
```

Here's a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/toxozibusu/1/edit?html,js,console,output) with working example. 
I used lodash v4.